# Google Tag Manager Data Layer Variable undefined - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am having trouble with an undefined data layer variable with Google Tag Manager named `ecomm_totalvalue` (Please note I have also tried `object.ecomm_totalvalue`)

I am using WordPress/WooCommerce and GTM with [duracelltomi-google-tag-manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duracelltomi-google-tag-manager/) to create and access the data layer.

The data layer works correctly and using the GTM inspector/preview I can view all the DLVariables (See image 1), however, they come up as undefined when I make data layer variables in Google Tag Manager and try to log them to the console with a GTM tag.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here as the variables exist, I assume I am not calling them correctly!

Any help would be appreciated, please view images for more information.

Thank you!

### Image 1 - GTM Preview

[image]

### Image 2 - Data Layer Variable

[image]

### Image 3 - Tag

[image]

---

`(6) [Arguments(2), Arguments(2), {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, object_observed: true, push: ƒ]
0: Arguments(2) ["js", Sun Sep 23 2018 17:54:21 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
1: Arguments(2) ["config", "UA-01234567-1", callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
2:
customerBillingAddress1: ""
customerBillingAddress2: ""
customerBillingCity: ""
customerBillingCompany: ""
customerBillingCountry: ""
customerBillingEmail: ""
customerBillingFirstName: ""
customerBillingLastName: ""
customerBillingPhone: ""
customerBillingPostcode: ""
customerFirstName: ""
customerLastName: ""
customerShippingAddress1: ""
customerShippingAddress2: ""
customerShippingCity: ""
customerShippingCompany: ""
customerShippingCountry: ""
customerShippingFirstName: ""
customerShippingLastName: ""
customerShippingPostcode: ""
customerTotalOrderValue: "0.00"
customerTotalOrders: 0
ecomm_pagetype: "other"
pagePostAuthor: "user"
pagePostType: "page"
pagePostType2: "single-page"
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Downvote :( harsh

Comment: Could you please update the full list of the datalayer?

Comment: Hey @M.Kooi, is that what you need ^ updated Q

Comment: why is this downvoted? this is a great question with lots of info?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ecomm_totalvalue` in your data layer variable and make sure your tag is firing after the data layer variable is available. No need to test the variable in a custom HTML tag, you can see the value in the preview panel.